# Getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool is closed" exception during getTx() call

Tags: orientdb

I am getting below exceptions in the logs, related to orientdb (2.2.19)

```
SYS_ERR: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool is closed
> 
> at
> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.checkForClose(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:370)
> 
> at
> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.acquire(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:176)
> 
> at
> com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.<init>(OrientBaseGraph.java:143)
> 
> at
> com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.<init>(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:77)
> at
> com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph.<init>(OrientGraph.java:135)
> at
> com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory$1.getGraph(OrientGraphFactory.java:84)
> 
> at
> com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory.getTx(OrientGraphFactory.java:221)
```

The code mainly perform adding the data in orientdb, and while getting the OrientGraphFactory.getTx() call, I am seeing all these exception.

I am calling commit() call, and then doing shutdown()

```
private void commitGraph(OrientBaseGraph graph){
        try{
            graph.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            graph.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Also these exception cased after NPE, while performing commit

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.makeActive(OrientBaseGraph.java:362)
        at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.commit(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:177)
```

The OrientGraphFactory is initialized as below

```
factory = new OrientGraphFactory(url, userName, password).setupPool(1,50);
```

Any pointers, when and why this error is thrown would be helpful.

**Edit:**

The configuration in my orientdb-server-config.xml is as below :

```
 <parameters>
                <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="50" name="graph.pool.max"/>
            </parameters>
```

I could see that there are many exceptions for not reaching the remote server having orientdb installation. Is it something related to it. I could see the below exception

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot create a connection to remote server address(es)
```

Comment: are you sharing the graph between different threads?

Comment: @Luigi, Each thread gets its own OrientGraph (transaction connection) and then after calling commit, it calls shutdown. I have single instance for OrientGraphFactory, which is used for getting OrientGraph and OrientGraphNoTx.